# find minimal and maximum element in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose I am maintaining a set of integers (will add/remove dynamically, and the integers might have duplicate values). And I need to efficiently find max/min element of the current element set. Wondering if any better solutions?

My current solution is maintain a max heap and a min heap. I am using Python 2.7.x and open for any 3rd party pip plug-ins to fit my problem.

Comment: How about keeping two variables `max` and `min`. And keep them updated as and when new integers arrive? This should work as you said the adding and removing is dynamic.

Comment: @Haris, thanks for the advice, but I need to dynamically remove elements as well, for example, if I remove the maximum element, I need to find the 2nd maximum quickly. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: Just a language note: "minimal" means the smallest possible value. You want the "minimum", the smallest value actually present in your set.

Comment: Thanks for the correction beaker, yes, I need to find the smallest and largest element. If you have better ideas, which is more elegant/efficient than maintaining two heaps, appreciate to share. :)

Comment: Another lunguistic nitpick: you said you are maintaining a "set of integers". But it might have duplicates. So it's not actually a set in python terms. It is a list.

Comment: @SaqibAli, nice catch and vote up. But the problem is the same, how to find largest and smallest elements ASAP, which maintain efficient insert/delete. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function. There is no point in maintaining the heap. You need min/max heap if you want to perform this action (getting min/max) many times while adding removing elements.

Do not forget that to build a heap you need to spend O(n) time, where the constant is 2 (as far as I remember). Only then you can use it's `O(log(n))` time to get your min/max.

---

**P.S.** Ok now that you have told that you have to call  min/max many times you have to make two heaps (min heap and max heap). It will take `O(n)` to construct each heap, then each operation (add element, remove element, find min/max) will take `O(log(n))`, where you add/remove elements to both heaps and do min/max on the corresponding heap.

Where as if you will go with min/max functions over the list, your do not need to construct anything and add will take `O(1)`, remove `O(n)`, and min/max `O(n)`, which is way worse than heap.

**P.P.S** [python has heaps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)

Comment: Hi Salvador, I definitely need to call max/min frequently. Almost the same frequency as add/remove, the use case is, when add/remove, I need to find new max/min. Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa then you should clearly use heap and forget about max/min.

Comment: Thanks Salvador, you mentioned, "Each will take O(n) then each operation", I am wondering you are referring to which operation?

Comment: @LinMa that was a typo. Changed it.

Comment: Thanks Salvador, I am thinking is more elegant data structure to be used? Currently, I am maintaining two data structures -- a max heap and a min heap, and wondering if you have smart ideas to use a single data structure? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Salvador. Mark your reply as answered.

Answer (score 1):

> min(list_of_ints)

Will yield your minimum of the list and...

> max(list_of_ints)

Will yield your maximum of the list.

Hope that helps....

Comment: Thanks hd1, I think it is O(n) complexity? Even worse than my current heap solution to find max/min. :)

Comment: I think the OP was asking for a better efficient solution then that. This would essentially traverse the whole list.

Comment: Yes, @Haris has got the initiative why I am asking. I need to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: @Lin Ma you'll have to write your own routine in C then, as both min and max look [pretty optimal to me for integers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/decimal.py).

Comment: Thanks hd1, confused by what do you mean my own routine? Is there any Python built-in or 3rd party container I can use directly? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa what are the performance characteristics of min and max that you find so bad?

Comment: Thanks hd1, you mean using heap or using list?

Answer (score 1):

Using sorted list may help. First element will always be minimum and last element will always be maximum, with O(1) complexity to get the value.

Using binary search to add/remove with sorted list will be O(log(n))

Comment: Thanks Ashish, for SortedList, which data structure/class do you mean in Python?

Comment: I think you will have to create your own class. Here is one such implementation. http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/python/summerfield/py3/SortedList.py

Comment: Thanks Ashish, for sorted list, add/remove elements are slower than Python dictionary? Thanks.